# "File does not contain a valid CIL image" error while executing file with mono

Tags: mono

I am trying to run `superoneclick` using mono. I tried the following command

```
mono ./superoneclick.exe
```

I also tried

```
mono superoneclick.exe
```

But both give an error stating

```
Cannot open assembly 'superoneclick.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

What should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't do something in special mode. Your `superoneclick.exe` will not run on Mono. Try with [Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine/).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu According to the developer, this program is to be executed using mono.I still tried with wine, but it failed miserably with some `biclient.exe` error.

Comment: @RegisteredUser have you solved this problem?

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht I'm not sure, but it's highly unlikely, as this seems to be related to rooting an android, and the device I had back then was never rooted.